# Not able to see Public Groups when sharing files

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, sharing, configuration

I'm trying to share files with my users. I can see individual users, but can't access the groups. My Public Groups don't populate in the Groups dropdown list, and if I just type in the group name, no sharing happens. The group is also not added to the library.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're not able to share the files into `Setup >> Group >> Public group List (anyone group)` directly in Salesforce via UI. It's an Out of box functionality.

You can able to share the files into

- People
- Private/Public chatter group
- Library
- anyone with Link (public link)

To share the files into other **Chatter group(public/private)/people**, As per [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_change_access.htm&type=5) you need to have `Viewer/Collaborator/File Owner` access to share that particular file into others.

Once you having the proper access, you can search the **public/private chatter group** in that `Groups` option to share.

So please make sure, you're having the proper permission to share the file.

Thanks.

Comment: I am a file owner, still not able to see public groups while sharing files.

Comment: you mean "public chatter groups"?

Comment: you can only allow to share private/public chatter groups as follows ref:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_sharing_groups.htm&type=5. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: not public chatter groups, just Groups.  Setup -> Pubic Group. These should appear while sharing files.

Comment: you can't share the files into group directly in Salesforce via UI. It's an Out of box functionality at this moment. you can collect the users and share the file's link (public link) via email or message. I have updated the answer also for better clarity.

Comment: but if see the screenshot, on UI we have option to share with Groups.

Comment: It's indicates the group as `Collaborator/Chatter` group not a Public group which used on sharing rules.